# Improving speed of a Stan program for hierarchical logit/probit models

Tags: performance, hierarchical, stan

I use the following code to estimate a hierarchical logit model.

```
data {
  int<lower=1> D;   // number of covariates
  int<lower=0> N;   // number of observations
  int<lower=1> L;   // number of groups (levels)
  int<lower=0,upper=1> y[N];  // binary response
  int<lower=1,upper=L> ll[N];    // group ids
  row_vector[D] x[N];   //covariates
}
parameters {
  real mu[D];
  real<lower=0> sigma[D];
  vector[D] beta[L];
}
model {
  
  mu ~ normal(0, 100);  // prior for mu
//  sigma ~ uniform(0, 100) ; // prior for sigma
  for (l in 1:L) beta[l] ~ normal(mu, sigma);
  
  {
    vector[N] x_beta_ll;
    for (n in 1:N) x_beta_ll[n] = x[n] * beta[ll[n]];
    y ~ bernoulli_logit(x_beta_ll);
  }
}
```

For my data, N = 264,713 (number of total observations), L = 10,000 (the number of groups), D = 26 (the number of covariates). Then, I have this message, and it takes an extremely long time to sample:

```
Chain 1: Gradient evaluation took 0.131 seconds
Chain 1: 1000 transitions using 10 leapfrog steps per transition would take 1310 seconds.
Chain 1: Adjust your expectations accordingly!
```

I wonder if there is a good way to improve speed. BTW, this is the R code that I used:

```
fit <- stan(
  file = "hierarchical_logit.stan",  # Stan program
  data = data,    # named list of data
  chains = 1,             # number of Markov chains
  warmup = 1000,          # number of warmup iterations per chain
  iter = 2000,            # total number of iterations per chain
  cores = 5,              # number of cores (could use one per chain)
  verbose = TRUE
)
```

I would appreciate a tip from experts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that it looks like your priors are likely to be very bad in the context of a logit transformation. It depends on what the variables you are supplying are, but my guess is that it will be placing almost all the density for these at 0 and 1. For continuous variables, if you are supplying standardised variables at the outset, these will imply probabilities that step from 0 to 1 in no space at all, and, similarly, for the intercept terms most of the density will be at 0 and 1 too. It'd be worth thinking about these- and try simulating it, e.g. in R the prior on any intercept terms is `hist(boot::inv.logit(rnorm(1000, 0, 100)), breaks = 100))`. A much healthier, uninformative prior on an intercept-term, for example, would be something like a `normal(0, 1.5)` which is roughly uniform between [0,1] on the probability scale (as recommended by McElreath)). Similar thinking and simulation will help you figure out priors for the other variables (I don't know what they are). Supplying some common-sense priors might well with speed, depending on what your variables are/data look like, and are important regardless.

Unless there is some particular reason not to, the first thing I would do is just run the model with brms or rstanarm. It's a standard model and these will automatically run a model that is well-formulated and you can just use lmer-type syntax. If that is still prohibitively slow then you will need to do some additional work.

If you want to do it yourself (/brms has been too slow), make sure you are passing in standardised variables, or standardise them within your model (https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_25/stan-users-guide/standardizing-predictors-and-outputs.html).

At the moment you have a centered parameterisation- a non-centered parameterisation can be much faster, so if it's slow it would be worth trying this (there's a section on it in the Stan manual). It would look something like this:

```
parameters {
  real mu[D];
  real<lower=0> sigma[D];
  vector[D] beta_z[L];
}
transformed parameters {
  vector[D] beta[L];
  for(l in 1:L){
    beta[l] = mu + sigma * beta_z[l];
  }
}
model {
...as before, but replace beta[l] ~ normal(mu, sigma) with...
for (l in 1:L) beta_z[l] ~ normal(0, 1);
}
```

Finally you can write a model that uses within-chain parallelisation for major speedups. It is however a bit of effort to do and I wouldn't do it until you've found that the simpler steps are still too slow. See https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/reduce_sum_tutorial.html for a worked example.

Also, for questions about Stan, the [Stan discourse](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/) is very good- there are probably other things that you might do that haven't occurred to me..

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I confirm that the prior has no problem.